# Right click menu within a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have a foreach loop where I am parsing a json return. Parsing works and I am able to echo what I need. Each return is displayed in a table cell.

I want to have a right click menu in each table cell with a hyperlink where the return will also appear. I have tried a few right click examples and no matter where I put the right click menu, I always see the last item in the loop appear in the hyper link.

My hyperlink is

```
      <a href = "test.com?cmd=<?php echo $json_item;?>ITEM_1</a>
```

While the table cells all display $json_item properly, the right menu item ITEM_1 is displaying the last value of $json_item

Comment: You might want to try this first to see what is best to post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post your iteration code so we can determine if it is hoisting-related

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was hoisting related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code looks like this:

```
var txt = ["a","b","c"];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) { 
   var msg = txt[i];
    setTimeout(function() { alert(msg); }, i*1000);        
}​

// Alerts 'c', 'c', 'c'
```

Your problem is [hoisting](https://codeburst.io/hoist-your-knowledge-of-javascript-hoisting-59b73124b430) related:

ref: http://ignaciothayer.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/